Android - listFiles() does not return files
I've successfully written and read files in the internal storage. So far, so good.
However, I cannot list the files in the storage. listFiles() only returns one single file,
"profileInstalled". There are three more files in the directory in this sample run.
When tried with varying amounts of files, listFiles() have never returned more than
that one file.
The documentation of java.io.File.listFiles in Android Studio does not
hint anything about this peculiarity. It says that a security manager,
if existing, may throw a SecurityException, but that doesn't happen here.
I've tried hints from other discussions at StackOverflow, but to no avail. I've configured
all permissions I could find relevant.
I expect four files to be returned, and not only one.
Details from Device Explorer
Output on screen
The images seem broken. I'll describe them as text:
The Device Explorer shows this list:
org.filemanager            drwx------ 2024-08-22 12:02   4 KB
    cache                  drwx------ 2024-08-22 12:02   4 KB
    code_cache             drwxrws--- 2024-08-22 12:04   4 KB
    files                  drwxrws--- 2024-08-22 12:04   4 KB
        profilesInstalled  -rw------- 2024-08-22 12:04  24  B
    files:z1.txt           -rw------- 2024-08-22 12:14   3  B
    files:z2.txt           -rw------- 2024-08-22 12:14   3  B
    files:z3.txt           -rw------- 2024-08-22 12:14   3  B

The output on screen is as follows:
list files in: /data/user/0/org.filemanager/files:
0 /data/user/0/org.filemanager/files/profilesInstalled;
End

Using Android Studio Iguana with its emulating device, running Android 14.
MainActivity.java:
package org.filemanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private File directory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        directory = this.getFilesDir();
       
        save("z1.txt", "foo");
        save("z2.txt", "fie");
        save("z3.txt", "fum");

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("list files in: " + directory + ":\n");
        File[] ea = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < ea.length; ++i) {
            builder.append(i + " " + ea[i] + ";\n");
        }
        builder.append("End");

        TextView view = findViewById(R.id.id1);
        // Run code on Main/UI thread
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
            view.setText(builder.toString());
        });
    }

    private void save(String filename, String data) {
        try {
            File file = new File(directory + File.pathSeparator + filename);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                outputStream.write(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"
        tools:ignore="SelectedPhotoAccess"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FileManager"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.FileManager">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>


The problem is this line:
File file = new File(directory + File.pathSeparator + filename);

This creates a file in the parent of directory with the directories name followed by ":" and filename as the name of the file.
File.pathSeparator is used to separate multiple directory paths in the PATH environment variable. A single directory path is separated using File.separator:
File file = new File(directory + File.separator + filename);

An even better solution would be not to manually concatenate paths but use the correct File constructor:
File file = new File(directory, filename);



When tried with varying amounts of files, listFiles() have never returned more than that one file.

There is only one file in that directory. Your screenshot and your text output line up. getFilesDir() is the filesystem path to the files/ directory in your screenshot, and there is only one file in the files/ directory.
